# Fit a linear line with CI to GEV distribution in R

Tags: r, regression, distribution

I have a data of 34 years of a variable Y. I want to fit a generalised extreme value distrbution (GEV) to this data.

I use the following code.

`df = structure(list(x = 1:35, y = c(176.55005072974, 136.609062033287, 
158.323835221524, 160.668521285558, 174.185742838285, 156.90073054748, 
158.045799551095, 186.696704141421, 169.388010854245, 169.023364381474, 
173.755336249718, 178.360257725013, 180.055691919144, 178.963782808454, 
176.309554924479, 176.869635838618, 181.870498315494, 189.611312902551, 
185.161870675961, 187.35139554664, 165.46966999563, 182.242441328656, 
186.244853297894, 188.453023779529, 191.97421050017, 191.041451101999, 
196.644472224133, 188.515454922651, 206.281311879478, 194.858834774533, 
223.552034677587, 207.730621173395, 214.28592077984, 257.861176094329, 
270.111968152873), type = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A")), .Names = c("x", "y", "type"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35"
), class = "data.frame")`

`##fit GEV distribution using package (extRemes)
library(extRemes)
GEV_MLE <- fevd(as.vector(df$y), method = "MLE", type="GEV")`

This helps me to fit the data to GEV distribution. Next thing I want to plot it.

`##plot the distribution
plot(GEV_MLE, type="rl",main="Return Level Plot MLE",ylim=c(100,500), pch=16)`[image]

The fit is mainly based on the MLE approach. Instead of a nonlinear fit, I want to have a linear fit to the points and the corresponding CI as shown in figure below.[image]

Can any one help me with this?